# auditd cache activity filtering?

Tags: cache, rules, auditd

Can anyone suggest a strategy for filtering browser cache activity from auditable events in CentOS6. Apparently el7 has added capabilities for filtering on executables? But all of our workstation instances are still on 6. I have requirements that prevent me from just yanking the rule that produces the traffic in the first place.

```
<86>1 2018-02-23T10:10:13.805049-08:00 xxxxxxxx2 audisp-graylog  - -  {"audit_category":"write","audit_summary":"Write: /home/joeblow/.cache/mozilla/firefox/udlgt3qa.default/safebrowsing-to_delete/test-phish-simple.pset","audit_hostname":"xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx","audit_timestamp":"2018-02-23T10:10:13-0800","audit_plugin":"audisp-graylog","audit_version":"1.0.0","audit":{"serial":"198286","rdev":"00:00","ogid":"995220534","ouid":"995220534","mode":"040700","dev":"fd:04","inode":"3678454","path":"/home/xxxxxx/.cache/mozilla/firefox/udlgt3qa.default/safebrowsing-to_delete/test-phish-simple.pset","serial":"198286","rdev":"00:00","ogid":"995220534","ouid":"995220534","mode":"040700","dev":"fd:04","inode":"3678454","path":"/home/xxxxxxx/.cache/mozilla/firefox/udlgt3qa.default/safebrowsing-to_delete/","serial":"198286","cwd":"/home/trwhite1","serial":"198286","session":"1","fsgid":"995220534","sgid":"995220534","egid":"995220534","fsuid":"995220534","suid":"995220534","euid":"995220534","gid":"995220534","pid":"3934","ppid":"1","process":"/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox","tty":"(none)","uid":"995220534","user":"xxxxxxx","originaluid":"995220534","originaluser":"xxxxxxx","parentprocess":"init","auditkey":"delete","processname":"55524C20436C6173736966696572","serial":"198286"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can collect those logs with collector sidecar, http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/collector_sidecar.html
2. Then parse via pipeline rules (You can write rules according to your needs).
3. After all of it, try Quick Values widget for a cool dashboard.